# acknowledgement page in latex.How to create the following acknowledgement page

Tags: biblatex

[image]

I am trying to create this in latex. but I am not able to do this. Please help how to form this in latex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?